# Flush AFP client cache

Tags: file-sharing, afp

I have an AFP server with netatalk on a Linux box, which maintains CNIDs separate from the actual files. Due to a faulty disk (or rather, three of them in a RAID6), the database with the CNID mapping got corrupted and needed to be rebuilt, which caused new CNIDs to be generated for some files.

The result is that the clients' cache is inconsistent with the server state, as the clients assume that CNIDs are never recycled.

I'd thus need a way to flush the cache on the clients, and ideally also a switch to disable client side caching, so the users can continue working if I ever need to rebuild the database again.

Comment: Are these clients Macs?

Comment: Yes, they are, running different versions of OS X.